# EOF eror while running a script

Tags: pycharm, eof

I am working on simple game project, this part where you are moving between the rooms.This code work in PYthonTutot, but doesn't in Pycharm. What am I missing? Thank you in advance

#A dictionary for the simplified dragon text game
#The dictionary links a room to other rooms.
rooms = {
'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
}

```
# Let's start from the Great Hall
starting_room = 'Great Hall'

# set current room to use in the gameplay loop
current_room = starting_room

while True:
    print("\nYou are currently in {}".format(current_room))

# let the user enter a command to move as 'go direction' or 'exit'
# first we split the input by space, then take the last part, capitalize first letter
# if 'go direction' ==> 'Direction'
# if 'exit' ==> 'Exit'
move = input("Enter 'go North/South/East/West' to move or 'Exit': ").split()  [-1].capitalize()

# user to exit
if move == 'Exit':
    current_room = 'exit'
    break
elif move in rooms[current_room]:      # a valid move
     current_room = rooms[current_room][move]

# invalid move
else:
      print("Invalid Move. There's no room to the {}".format(move))

You are currently in Great Hall
Enter 'go North/South/East/West' to move or 'Exit': go south
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/tanyapryma/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line 36, in <module>
move = input("Enter 'go North/South/East/West' to move or 'Exit': ").split()[-1].capitalize()
```

File "", line 1
go south
^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Python are you using?

If in 2.X, try:

```
move = raw_input("Enter 'go North/South/East/West' to move or 'Exit': ").split()[-1].capitalize()
```

Comment: Glad it worked :)  You might want to upload your Python version so that you avoid other future problems.